# Why does Bitlocker keep on showing me this error?

Tags: bitlocker

Bitlocker keeps on showing that "an error occurred" and points to a "hardware fault". However, even after I ran chkdsk /r, I keep on getting this error when decrypting.

Here's an image of the error described above:

[image: error]

Comment: Need more information. SSD or traditional drive? Is it the system drive? Is it Sata, USB? Are you sure the disk isn't failing? Check the application log in event viewer for source chkdsk to get the results of a couple of the past scans and share the details with us.

Comment: This is a 500GB HDD, system drive, sata. And the disk is not failing

Answer (score 1):

Probably `chkdsk /r` found some errors but didn't repaired them all, so a more exhaustive check is necessary. Run `chkdsk /r /f` and **restart twice**. This will ensure your data is recovered fully.

If this doesn't work, then read the last part of the message:

> If these errors persist this may be indicative of a hardware fault.

In which case you may be looking for profesional help to recover your data.

Comment: it's says "Invalid parameter - /p" when I input "chkdsk /p /r /f" in the command prompt

Comment: @justin don't know where I saw that `/p`, in any case was a mistake, I removed it.

Comment: remember to run cmd as administrator

Comment: Sorry, this did not help at all. I still get the error shown above.

Comment: @justin see my update.

Answer (score 0):

Using /b will re-evaluate the clusters marked as bad. It is worth a try.

```
chkdsk /b
```

Likely you do have physical problem with the disk that **may** be a sign it is going to die. You can use [HDTUNE](http://www.hdtune.com/) or a similar program to monitor the SMART stats and perform some tests.

I have had many disk die a slow death and the common warning sign is if you keep running chkdsk and find more errors each time.

In any case be sure you have a full backup.

Comment: chkdsk /b still does not solve the problem for me.